# How to code if function

Tags: vba, excel

How to code if function

here is the equivalent formula in excel

if(Concrete_Class="A", volume*cementfactor,"")

```
Sub multiply()
    Dim second As Range
    Dim first As Range, prodt As Long
    Dim third As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long


    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    Set first = Range("volume")
    Set third = Range("Cement")
    Set second = Range("cementfactor")

    For i = 1 To LastRow
            third(i, 1) = first(i, 1) * second

    Next i

    Rows(LastRow).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A2").Select
End Sub
```

Example:

[image: img1]

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: nice use of named ranges! But what is your motivation to use VBA instead of native Excel, especially when your native Excel is simple and elegant?

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
Sub multiply()
    Dim second As Range
    Dim first As Range, prodt As Long
    Dim third As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long


    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    Set first = Range("volume")
    Set third = Range("Cement")
    Set second = Range("cementfactor")


    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = "A" Then
            third(i, 1) = first(i, 1) * second
        End If
    Next i

    Rows(LastRow).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A2").Select
End Sub
```